# simple download.file() in r is not working with requests.get

Tags: python, python-requests

I am attempting to convert R code to python code. There is a current line that I am having trouble with. (code snip 1).

I have tried all variations of requests and the python code is creating a blank file with none of the contents.

Requests, wget, urllib.requests, etc. etc.

(1)

```
downloader = download.file(url = 'https://www.equibase.com/premium/eqbLateChangeXMLDownload.cfm',destfile = 'C:/Users/bnewell/Desktop/test.xml",quiet = TRUE)              # DOWNLOADING XML FILE FROM SITE
        unfiltered = xmlToList(xmlParse(download_file))
```

(2)

```py
import requests

URL = 'https://www.equibase.com/premium/eqbLateChangeXMLDownload.cfm'

response = requests.head(URL, allow_redirects=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests, shutil

URL = 'https://www.equibase.com/premium/eqbLateChangeXMLDownload.cfm'

page = requests.get(URL, stream=True, allow_redirects=True,
                    headers={'user-agent': 'MyPC'})

with open("File.xml", "wb") as f:
    page.raw.decode_content = True

    shutil.copyfileobj(page.raw, f)
```

Manually adding a `user-agent` header the file download for some reason I'm not sure about.

I use `shutil` to download the raw file which could be replaced by `page.iter_content`

Answer (score 0):

try to actually `get` the request

```
import requests

URL = 'https://www.equibase.com/premium/eqbLateChangeXMLDownload.cfm'

response = requests.get(URL, headers={'allow_redirects':True})
```

Then you can access what you are downloading with `response.raw`, `response.text`, `response.content` etc.

For more details see the actual [docs](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content)

Comment: thanks for the response guys! I have tried all of this, and I am running the code and getting a blank file, when the full file in r. For some reason, when I do request.get, and the try .content on that get request, the content is not there like it is in r

Comment: Then you likely are missing a header or some other parameter on the request.  Do you want to post the R code in your question to see help compare?

Comment: Yes, posting now, currently in (1)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```py
import os
import requests

url = "htts://......"
r = requests.get(url , stream=True, allow_redirects=True)

if r.status_code != 200:
    print("Download failed:", r.status_code, r.headers, r.text)

file_path = r"C:\data\...."
with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 * 8):
        if chunk:
            f.write(chunk)
            f.flush()
            os.fsync(f.fileno())
```

Comment: what do you mean 0kb?

Comment: It doesn't download the file, the size is 0KB. it is nothing

Comment: It is not working for me either, the file appears in the destination section, but without the content like it does when I run r code.